# Receiving parameters from navigation in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to send a parameter through navigation. But the parameter Im receiving is always undefined.
I dont know what to try because I don't really know what is wrong with the code.

Here's where I send the parameter.

```
 return (
    <View>
      {info.map((l, i) => (
        <ListItem
          key={i}
          title={l.NombreCliente}
          subtitle={
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Abonos", { id: l.idClientes})} >
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  paddingLeft: 10,
                  paddingTop: 5
                }}
              >
                <Text> Telefono: {l.Telefono} </Text>
                <Text> Cumpleaños: {l.FechaDeNacimiento} </Text>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  paddingLeft: 10,
                  paddingTop: 5
                }}
              >
                <Text> Total Vendido: {l.total} </Text>
                <Text> Adeudo: {l.saldo_pendiente} </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
          bottomDivider
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
```

And here I receive and display the parameter.

```
const id = navigation.getParam("id");
console.log(id);

return(
    <View>
        <Text>
            El id del cliente es: {id}
        </Text>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to access to the navigation from the props and it should be something like this :

```
const id = this.props.navigation.getParam("id");
```

Comment: I have it like this:
`const Abono = ({navigation}) =>{ ..}`

Answer (score 0):

Used `this.props.navigation.state` it is most commonly used to access the params for the screen.

```
const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.id
```

Instead of accessing the param directly, you can call `getParam` to get a specific param value with a fallback.

```
const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('id', '2');
```

if `id` or `params` are `undefined`, set the fallback value `2`.